# Optimize a for loop applied on all elements of a df

Tags: python, loops, csv, pandas, dataframe

EDIT : here are the first lines :

```
df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(path, file), dtype = str,delimiter = ';',error_bad_lines=False, nrows=50)
df["CALDAY"] = df["CALDAY"].apply(lambda x:dt.datetime.strptime(x,'%d/%m/%Y'))
df = df.fillna(0)
```

I have a csv file that has 1500 columns and 35000 rows. It contains values, but under the form 1.700,35 for example, whereas in python I need 1700.35. When I read the csv, all values are under a str type.

To solve this I wrote this function :

```
def format_nombre(df):
    for i in range(length):
        for j in range(width):
            element = df.iloc[i,j]
            if (type(element) != type(df.iloc[1,0])):
                a = df.iloc[i,j].replace(".","")
                b = float(a.replace(",","."))
                df.iloc[i,j] = b
```

Basically, I select each intersection of all rows and columns, I replace the problematic characters, I turn the element into a float and I replace it in the dataframe. The if ensures that the function doesn't consider dates, which are in the first column of my dataframe.

The problem is that although the function does exactly what I want, it takes approximately 1 minute to cover 10 rows, so transforming my csv would take a little less than 60h.

I realize this is far from being optimized, but I struggled and failed to find a way that suited my needs and (scarce) skills.

Comment: What's the delimiter in your csv? for instance if it's not comma then the following would work `pd.read_csv(your_file, thousands='.', decimal=',', sep=some_separator)`

Comment: Also include first 5-6 lines of your file in the question and the format of DF which you are trying to construct.

Comment: I already tried and it doesn't work, the ',' remain and I am therefore unable to convert it to a float later on.

Comment: Mohammad what to you mean by "format of df" ? The idea is to start with strings, and to modify them to be able to turn them into floats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
def to_numeric(column):
    if np.issubdtype(column.dtype, np.datetime64):
        return column
    else:
        return column.str.replace('.', '').str.replace(',', '.').astype(float)

df = df.apply(to_numeric)
```

That's assuming all strings are valid. Otherwise use `pd.to_numeric` instead of `astype(float)`.

Comment: That being said, I'm surprised @EdChum's solution in the comments does not work.

Comment: This solution is perfect ! Thanks a lot !